# Uploading a file to Google Sheets using the Java API

Tags: java, google-sheets, playframework, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am looking for a way to write a function in Java that is called to upload a newly created  .xlsx file to Google Sheets. I could not find any solution to upload the file directly to Google Sheets and it was not even mentioned in the Google Sheets API docs. Is there any other way to handle this other than writing the sheet to the Google Spreadsheet cell by cell or uploading the file to Google Drive and than redirect it to Google Spreadsheets?